# cronjob in asp c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a question:

I have to do a project, which has something to do with reading data from txt into MSSQL. This function I solved it with a click-event. Right now, the reading process has to read the whole data automatically every day on the server, even without open the website. Can I do it with a cronjob or there are also other better solutions?

Comment: Did you try searching?

Comment: Windows includes a feature called Task Scheduler, write a C# Console Application and set it to run every x hours

Comment: @MarkMilford ah, I can set this task scheduler in c#? thank you for the new information, i will try it now

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, but I just can find the cronjob solution

Comment: Cron jobs are specific to *nix. In Windows it is called Scheduled Tasks, just like @MarkMilford says,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Quartz.NET you can also look at http://hangfire.io/.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Quartz.Net - it's a decent job-scheduling system.

It's probably overkill if you only have a single job.

Quickstart documentation is here: http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html